# how to move one image on background image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load 2 images in Qlabel. I want overlay car image

[image]

on background image

[image]

at a specific location lets say (x,y). I'm using Qt5.5.1. I'm calculating displacement of the car. Now I want to update the displacement of car on background image. This is how I load the images on button clicked

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonLdImg_clicked()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(imagePath);
    QPixmap pixmapcar(imagePathCar);
    ui->labelMainImg->setPixmap(pixmap);
    ui->labelMainImg->setPixmap(pixmapcar);
}
```

Comment: Two consecutive calls of `setPixmap` won't make the trick.
It's either you implement your own `paintEvent()` or just use QGraphicsScene (possible overkill, depending on what you make the drawing for)

Comment: One way is to merge 2 images into 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998850/how-to-merge-two-images-into-one-using-qimage-and-qpainter-in-qt

And other way is to add second QLabel and set pixmap of the car in the separate QLabel

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!
 As per @MasterAler I have implemented my own way paintevent() using **Qpainter**.

Comment: @Angel.Risteski the Link you provided helped. I used **setCompositionMode** and after that **drawImage**.